# it was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]
React Routing Problem. I Install react-router-dom but it don't work how can i fix

[image]
This tutorial will be reading page. but my pc don't lick this

Comment: Please share all code examples as properly formatted and readable code snippets instead of images. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is `react-router-dom@5` code (*i.e. the `Redirect`, `Switch`, etc*) but the error indicates you have installed the latest major version, `react-router-dom@6`.

Either revert back to v5 with the following CLI commands:

```
npm uninstall --save react-router-dom
npm install --save react-router-dom@5
```

Or keep RRDv6 installed and follow the [v5 migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) to update/replace the components and hooks that were replaced in RRDv6 from v5.

Answer (score 0):

useHistory was removed in react router dom v6.  Please use useNavigate instead.  Below is an example code of useNavigate.

In this example, I use the context API (a way of sharing state values across the application) to get a function to log out the user.  I then navigate them to the login page.

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../../context/AuthContext";

export default function Logout(){
    // in order to navigate, you need to first use the useNavigate hook.
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    //this is a function that logs out the user
    let {logoutUser} = useContext(AuthContext);


    //at the start, log out the user
    useEffect(()=>{
        logoutUser();
        //then -- and this is the part you want -- navigate them to the login page.
        navigate('/auth/login');
    },[])
    
}
```